# How to get all files in image directory Rails4 in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, directory, ruby-on-rails-4, assets

I have migrated from Rails3 to Rails4. The following code returns Array in Rails3 but in Rails4 it returns string with illegal character.

```
Dir.glob("app/assets/images/flowers/*")
```

sample output in Rails3

```
["app/assets/images/flowers/rose.png", "app/assets/images/flowers/lilly.png"]
```

output in Rails4

```
"\x04\b[dI\"8app/assets/images/flowers/rose.png\x06:\x06ETI\"4app/assets/images/flowers/lilly.png"
```

How to get same output format as in Rails3?

Comment: have you tried with `Dir.entries("app/assets/images/flowers")`?

Comment: yes, this throws 'No such file or directory' error

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 files = Dir.glob("app/assets/images/flowers/*").map do |f| File.basename f end
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dir` has nothing to do with Rails — it's pure Ruby class. [Here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html) is the API reference to it. According to API it should always return an Array. My guess is that you messed up something in your Ruby installation while you were upgrading Rails 3 to 4.

I think best bet will be a clean installation of ruby/rails. You could also try to run `Dir.glob()` from both IRB and rails console to see where the mistake happens; and start from there.